# Form ajax submit handler not called when loading in ModalDialog from submit handler of another form - Drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've custom form (suppose FORM1) with few fields and AJAX submit button. When user submit this form, I'm opening another form (suppose AJAXFORM1) in ModalDialog with few more fields and AJAX submit button. When I open AJAXFORM1 using link (i.e. `a` tag with 'use-ajax' class), form submit handler gets call and modal dialog is closing properly. But when I open AJAXFORM1 from submit handler of FORM1, form submit handler of AJAXFORM1 is not called (neither normal submit handler nor ajax callback). Below is code snippet I'm using:

FORM1

```
class CustomForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'custom_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = [];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#name' => 'submit',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxFormSubmit'],
      ],
    ];
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    return $form;
  }

  public function ajaxFormSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $options = [
    ];

    $modal_form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\mymodule\Form\ConfirmDialogForm', $options);
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand('My Modal Form', $modal_form));

    return $response;
  }

}
```

AJAXFORM1

```
class ConfirmDialogForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'confirm_dialog_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $options = []) {
    $form = [];

    $form['confirm'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Ok'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'submitModalFormAjax'],
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];

    $form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    \Drupal::logger('submit')->error('<pre>' . print_r($values, TRUE) . '</pre>');
    // return TRUE;
  }

  public function submitModalFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    $triggerd_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    \Drupal::logger('submit')->error('<pre>' . print_r($values, TRUE) . '</pre>');

    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    $redirect_to = 'redirect.to.route';
    $redirect_url = Url::fromRoute($redirect_to, [], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
    $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand($redirect_url));

    // $response->addCommand(new CloseDialogCommand());
    $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());

    return $response;
  }

}
```

Comment: ajaxFormSubmit does not return the original form

Comment: @IvanJaros can u elaborate more on 'ajaxFormSubmit does not return original form'.